# How to open layer 2 raw sockets in java?

Tags: java

How to open layer 2 raw sockets in java? In C we generally use AF_PACKET level for opening layer 2 raw sockets with sockaddr_ll structure. What's corresponding socket package for Layer 2 programming?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using a plain Java approach, since Java offers no networking support below layer 3. The only way is a workaround using the native `pcap` library via JNI. There are several Java libraries, that provide a higher level interface for that:

- https://github.com/mgodave/Jpcap (Can also write packages)
- http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/

EDIT: Updated broken link

Comment: First link is dead.