# Raw socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, raw-sockets

I am pretty new to java socket programming. I had already gone thorugh that java only deals with Internet Domain Sockets and it will support UDP and TCP and Raw IP Protocols. I want to know that is java support Raw Sockets without using any  third party applications? If it is possible can anyone help me with a small example? Any small advice will be very greatful!

Comment: if you want the source code on how java implements socket then take a look a the source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/Socket.java

Comment: is java support row socket?

Comment: TCP/IP and UDP are not raw sockets.

Comment: @duffymo The JDK/JRE do not support raw sockets.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas That i know. But it supports Raw IP protocol. Is it?

Comment: If you mean TCP/IP (and not HTTP, FTP, etc), then yes. java.net.Socket and java.net.ServerSocket.

Comment: Do you really need "raw" sockets? Then see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536232/how-to-open-layer-2-raw-sockets-in-java). Perhaps you just want to send data over TCP where a "regular" socket would be a better fit. Anyhow show what you have tried and found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to do RAW socket programming involving Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854961/best-way-to-do-raw-socket-programming-involving-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only really available support for [raw sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket) in Java standard library seems the [InetAddress.isReachable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29) that may do ICMP ping if permitted. This is really not much and probably even not really a raw socket, just one more protocol.

For other types of raw communication I would recommend to use [Berkley sockets under Linux](http://codebase.eu/tutorial/linux-socket-programming-c/) (root rights required) through some JNI - based wrapper.

Comment: See Comments to original post. All the "java.net" interface supports Berkley sockets protocols and is implemented inside the JVM.

Comment: "Raw sockets" in understand something that is capable of writing fully custom network packets, supporting things like arbitrary (not just ping) ICMP requests.

Comment: @JamesAnderson - your comment doesn't make any sense.  1) Berkeley sockets is an API not a protocol.  2) While the JVM may (or may not) use those C/C++ APIs internally, they are NOT directly available to Java code.